# wordpress nav sub menu goes under product name box

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress site which has plugin for navigation and plugin for product catalog. When submenu appears, product name box ( is handled by other plugin) layer goes above the sub menu.

Page example : http://mitraprestasiprima.com/cartel/

I have made the menu z layer to be higher than the product box z layer, 
however it still does not fix it.

Can anyone here give me lead how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is here :

[image]

add this code to your custom css it should solve your issue

```
  #primary .page .entry-content .al_archive h3.product-name .al_archive 
  .product-name {
   z-index: 1 !important;
     }
```

Comment: didnt work. I tried below too, which didnt work as well.
'
.ic-design.green-box.product-name  
 {
z-index: 2;
position:relative;
     }
.mega-menu-wrap-top
 {
z-index: 1;
position:relative;
     }'

Comment: ohh one sec let me check again the classes

Comment: .ic-design.green-box.product-name  
{
   z-index: 2;
  position:relative;
}
.product-list 
{
   z-index: 1;
  position:relative;
}

Comment: sure no problem